# Python 3 program to solve the quadratic formula raises SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python highlights the second quotation mark in the `"+i"` print statement of the `"discRoot > 0"` elif statement.

```
import math
def main():
    print("This program finds the real solutions to a quadratic equation.")
    a,b,c = 0.0,0.0,0.0
    a,b,c = float(input("n\Please enter the coefficients (a, b, c): "))
    discRoot = math.sqrt(b*b-4*a*c)
    if discRoot > 0:
        root1 = (-b + discRoot) / (2*a)
        root2 = (-b - discRoot) / (2*a)
        print("\nThe solutions are: ", root1, root2)
    elif discRoot < 0:
        print("\nThe solutions for this equation are not real.")
        root1 = (-b + (discRoot*-1)) / (2*a)
        root2 = (-b - (discRoot*-1)) / (2*a)
        print("\nThe solutions are: ", root1"+i" , root2"-i")
    else discRoot == 0:
        root1 = (-b + discRoot) / (2*a)
        root2 = (-b - discRoot) / (2*a)
        print("\nThe solutions are: ", root1, root2)



main()
```

Comment: _I'm getting a Syntax Error for no reason_ - no, you're getting a syntax error because your syntax is wrong.

Comment: someone already has :)

Answer (score 2):

This fixes the error in your complex root calculation as well ;-)

```
from math import sqrt

def get_float(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def main():
    print("This program solves a quadratic equation.")

    a = get_float("Value of coefficient A? ")
    b = get_float("Value of coefficient B? ")
    c = get_float("Value of coefficient C? ")

    print("\n{}x**2 + {}x + {} = 0 has ".format(a, b, c), end="")

    discriminant = b*b - 4*a*c
    if discriminant > 0:
        rt = sqrt(discriminant)
        root1 = (-b + rt) / (2 * a)
        root2 = (-b - rt) / (2 * a)
        print("two real solutions: {0:0.4f} and {1:0.4f}".format(root1, root2))
    elif discriminant == 0:
        root = -b / (2 * a)
        print("one real solution: {0:0.4f}".format(root))
    else:
        real = -b / (2 * a)
        # sign is irrelevant because we will +/- anyways;
        #   we want the +ve value for nicer output
        imag = abs(sqrt(-discriminant) / (2 * a))
        print("two complex solutions: {0:0.4f} + {1:0.4f}i and {0:0.4f} - {1:0.4f}i".format(real, imag))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which runs like

```
This program solves a quadratic equation.
Value of coefficient A? 1
Value of coefficient B? 1
Value of coefficient C? 1

1.0x**2 + 1.0x + 1.0 = 0 has two complex solutions: -0.5000 + 0.8660i and -0.5000 - 0.8660i
```

Answer (score 1):

This part here is a syntax error:

```
print("\nThe solutions are: ", root1"+i" , root2"-i")
```

I can't be sure of what you're trying to accomplish by this though. Perhaps you meant `str(root1)+ "i"`?

Also there's a syntax error in your else clause. Change it to `elif`:

```
elif discRoot == 0:
```

Or just use `else`:

```
else:
```

Comment: Well, i was going to ask that. What are you trying to do? Can you give me an example of the expected output?

Comment: When the discriminate of a quadratic equation is less than zero the solutions are non-real, IE you need to add i to the answer. Does that help at all? for example the root outputs could be "7+i" and "7-i"

Comment: Say it correctly!: When the discriminant is less than zero, the roots are complex. He's trying to use string formatting to print out an imaginary number, and getting both the answer and the formatting wrong.

Comment: So how would I do it then, Hugh?

Comment: @user3444785 Then for printing the result out, use the method mentioned in my answer. However, as for finding the correct answer, that's your work! :) Good luck

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    print "\nThe solutions are: ", root1,"+i " , root2,"-i"
```

Seperate strings and variables in print statement using ',' or else use str function

```
    print("\nThe solutions are: ", str(root1)+"+i "+str(root2)+"-i")
```

This is the correct sysntax:

```
    import math
    def main():
        print("This program finds the real solutions to a quadratic equation.")
        a,b,c = 0.0,0.0,0.0
        a,b,c = [float(x) for x in (input("\nPlease enter the coefficients (a, b, c): ").split(","))]
        if b*b-4*a*c <0 :  discRoot = math.sqrt(-(b*b-4*a*c)) * -1
        else :  discRoot = math.sqrt(b*b-4*a*c)
        if discRoot > 0:
            root1 = (-b + discRoot) / (2*a)
            root2 = (-b - discRoot) / (2*a)
            print("\nThe solutions are: ", root1, root2)
        elif discRoot < 0:
            print("\nThe solutions for this equation are not real.")
            root1 = (-b + (discRoot*-1)) / (2*a)
            root2 = (-b - (discRoot*-1)) / (2*a)
            print("\nThe solutions are: "+str(root1)+"+i"+str(root2)+"-i")
        elif discRoot == 0: #sdf
            root1 = (-b + discRoot) / (2*a)
            root2 = (-b - discRoot) / (2*a)
            print("\nThe solutions are: ", root1, root2)



    main()
```

Output:

```
     python3 a.py                                                                   
     This program finds the real solutions to a quadratic equation.                                   
     Please enter the coefficients (a, b, c):  1.0,2.9,3.0                                           

     The solutions for this equation are not real.

     The solutions are: -0.502635233925+i-2.39736476607-i
```

Comment: When I tried that the syntax error moved to "discRoot" in line 16

Comment: use elif:  elif discRoot == 0:  else wont look for a condition.

Comment: When I try to run that it still says syntax error, just in a different place. Very Strange. I copied that directly into Python

Comment: Are you sure that you have indented the code properly? make sure that there is no leading spaces before import, function etc

Comment: I'm sure. I think this is just a weird bug within python. I admit i forgot to add an extra = sign, but it still isn't running even after i corrected that.

Comment: Please try the updated code.  You can't take the square root of a negative number with math.sqrt()

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax error seems to be here:

```
print("\nThe solutions are: ", root1"+i" , root2"-i")
```

When you use the `+` to concatenate two items, it should be **out** of the quotations... You might want to change the line to this:

```
print("\nThe solutions are: ", str(root1) + "i" , str(root2) + "-i")
```

Or, you might have wanted this, depending on how you are going about solving the quadratic.

```
print("\nThe solutions are: ", str(root1) + "+i" , str(root2) + "-i")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def main():
    print("This program finds the real solutions to a quadratic equation.")
    a,b,c = 0.0,0.0,0.0
    a,b,c = float(input("n\Please enter the coefficients (a, b, c): "))
    discRoot = math.sqrt(b*b-4*a*c)
    if discRoot > 0:
        root1 = (-b + discRoot) / (2*a)
        root2 = (-b - discRoot) / (2*a)
        print("\nThe solutions are: ", root1, root2)
    elif discRoot < 0:
        print("\nThe solutions for this equation are not real.")
        root1 = (-b + (discRoot*-1)) / (2*a)
        root2 = (-b - (discRoot*-1)) / (2*a)
        print "\nThe solutions are: ", root1,"+i " , root2,"-i"
    elif discRoot == 0:   #Or use else without any condition
        root1 = (-b + discRoot) / (2*a)
        root2 = (-b - discRoot) / (2*a)
        print("\nThe solutions are: ", root1, root2)
    else :
       continue      



main()
```

Comment: still says invalid syntax.

Comment: @user3444785 : can u pl share the exact error? It should be with indentation I guess.

Comment: the error is jumping around the code, even when I haven't changed anything. It's very very strange.

Comment: Use input individually for a, b and c! and then convert them to float, this would help for sure!

Comment: This code (A) does not even run in Python 3 (line 14, print function has no brackets); (B) will give a runtime failure trying to unpack a float to three variables (line 4); and (C) why on Earth did you think a `continue` was needed (line 20)?